# JDA Lavaplayer bot doesn't work without changing .jar file

Tags: java, discord, bots, lavaplayer

I have a java Discord bot running JDA Version 5.0.0-beta.20 and lavaplayer version 1.3.77. This bot worked very well, but I decided to update the command system. I created a new branch on my GitHub project to update the system without changing the working bot. After updating the command system (I implemented slash commands) I've tested the new version of the bot. It joins my channel, but it doesn't play music. Then I've tested if my old jar with the bot that worked well still works and there is the same problem for this .jar file without changing anything to it. I already tried to update/downgrade both JDA and lavaplayer version. I also removed the bot from my test discord server and added it new (with administration permission). But it still doesn't work. Could it be a bug from lavaplayer/JDA? Or do I have to change anything?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a simalar issue a few days ago. My bot also fetches songs, but doesn't play any audio. I still haven't found an answer. Looks like a Lavalink or YouTube bug.

Comment: Okay, if I find any solution I will comment it here. Would be great if you would do so too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).